# Golang: Ping succeed the second time even if database is down

Tags: sql, go

I have run into an interesting issue, namely, that db.Ping() does not return an error even if the database has been killed since the first attempt.

Source code below:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type database struct {
    datasource string
    conn       *sql.DB
}

// Connect creates and initialises a Database struct
func (db *database) Connect(server, user, password, DBPort string) error {
    var err error

    db.datasource = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/", user, password)
    db.conn, err = sql.Open(server, db.datasource)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = db.conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        db.conn.Close()
        return err
    }

    log.Println("Waiting for 15 seconds, kill the DB")
    <-time.After(15 * time.Second)

    err = db.conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        db.conn.Close()
        return err
    }

    log.Println("Second ping successful")

    return nil
}
```

At first, the database is up, so the first Ping succeeds. However, I put a delay in there just for the sake of testing. In that 15 seconds I stop the database (`sudo service mysql stop`), however, db.Ping() still succeeds.

If I were to execute any actual query (via `db.Query`, `db.QueryRow` or `db.Exec`), then the sql package would panic with Broken Pipe (which is expected).

Am I doing something wrong?

also: go version go1.7.1 linux/amd64

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ping, after the first connection, doesn't actually *ping the database*.  It's odd, and wrong, but that's the way it works (until [Go 1.8](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F778e7ZSNiSmbju3jsEWzShcb8lIO4kDyfKDNm4PNd8/edit)).  If there's an existing connection in the connection pool that hasn't timed out, Ping will simply remove it from the pool and return it to you, without actually bothering to check if the database is still there.

Kardianos (who wrote the above linked document, as well as Govendor) fixed this in 1.8, provided the database driver supports it.  Until then, however, Ping isn't reliable for determining if the database is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Do you happen to know how I could test whether the database is still up?

Comment: Only way I can think of at the moment is running a no-op query (ex. `SELECT WHERE 1=0`) against the DB and seeing if it panics (via `recover()`).  That, or opening a second connection to the DB and then closing it (which only validates that the database still exists and is accessible, not that your original connection is still functional).

Comment: Thanks once again! I went with replacing the second `Ping()` with my own `Alive()` method, which tries to run a query like the one you shared, recovers from the panic if it happens and returns an error instead.

This way, the server stays up and can report that the database is temporarily down.

Cheers!