# sql.DB.Ping() not returning error when DB is down

Tags: go

I intentionally stopped the database after successfully launching my Go program to test the behavior of sql.DB.Ping().

sql.Open is being called in init()

Much to surprise, sql.DB.Ping() did not return an error when my program called it before calling sql.DB.Query().

Why am I doing this?
Just trying to write robust code. Checking the integrity of the DB connection only at startup may not be sufficient for a long-lived production web application.

Comment: Wjat drover do you use?

Comment: Since `sql.DB.Query()` will return an error if the connection is closed, pinging the database is redundant and introduces a race condition (the handle might close between the ping and the query). Handle the query error instead. If the error is because the connection is closed, reconnect and retry.

Comment: @Schwern there are valid uses for `Ping()`, such as a health check that doesn't intend to execute any query, just checks to verify that the DB is reachable. @Lee what database and driver are you using?

Comment: A possible answer to this question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619206/4511560

Comment: I've run into an issue where when the Db* is not set properly, Ping() fails to return at all, and hangs indefinitely.  This certainly seems wrong (Go 1.11)